# identify html in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have use web service in my windows application. webservice return string like:

```
<b>sdfsdf</b> 
<img alt="*" src="df"/>
```

is any way in windows form that read html tag. like if `<b/>` then text is bold. and `<img/>` image should apear not text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use a WebBrowser control, I suppose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Load your XML string into an XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(webservice_output_string);
```

Then you can use XPath against the document:

```
string bold = (doc.SelectSingleNode("//b") as XmlElement).InnerText;
string src = (doc.SelectSingleNode("//img/@src") as XmlAttribute).Value;
```

Comment: It's not XML it's HTML. Most HTML isn't valid XML - so he will get a runtime error in most cases. Furthermore, he wants to display the HTML - not extract data from it.